# link path not working as expected :reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]
[image]

as u can see I have a `Details` component under my `Search` component. when I click the button in it hides and loads `InnerDetail.js` this works fine

I have a `Search` component in both these pages when I search from any page and click on the `li` I want it to load the `InnerDdetails.js`

I have this booking button that when clicked will open this `<InnerDetail />` the URL path will be such that `/doctor/id`

details.js

```
const [detail, setDetail] = useState(false);

function OpenInner() {
   setDetail(true);
}

return ( 
  <>
    {detail ? (
        <InnerDetail />
      ) : (  
        <Link
           to={{ 
             pathname: "/doctor/" + personData.id,
             state: { id: personData.id, data: personData },
           }}
           onClick={OpenInner}
         >
           <button style={styles.book}>Book Appointments</button>
         </Link>
      )}
  </>
)
```

serch.js

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/doctor/ ` + suggestion.id, }}
  <li> suggestion.name</li>
</Link>
```

I have this link which is a search component this does not open my  `<InnerDetail />`

what I am trying to do is to open  `<InnerDetail />` when I type URL as `localhost/doctor/id`

**note** id can be any id

Comment: You can 
use 
history

Comment: details.js works fine what i am trying to do is in serch .js

Comment: You can use import { useHistory } from 'react-router'; let history = useHistory(); function OpenInner() { history.push("YOUR PATH ") setDetail(true); };

Comment: i have inserted 2 images so that u can uderstand what is my probelm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that. let's implement it step by step:

First, you need a method to get the current page's URL. there are many implementations to doing this like using `useLocation` or `useHistory` which is come from the `react-router-dom` library. also, there is a built-in method to get the pathname from the URL using in this way:

```
// for example consider this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505097
const pathname = windows.location.pathname

console.log(pathname) // the result ----> /questions/69505097
```

Now, you can get the pathname from the `URL` which in your case it will be `/doctor/id`

splitting the result with `.split("/")` and then get the `id` from it:

```
const pathname = windows.location.pathname
const doctorId = pathname.split("/")[2]
```

Now, in the `Details` component, you need to implement the above method in a `useEffect` hook. also, another state value needed to store that `doctorId`.

```
const [hasId, setHasId] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const pathname = windows.location.pathname
  const doctorId = pathname.split("/")[2]
  
  if(doctorId){
     setHasId(true)
  } else {
     setHasId(false)
  }
}, [])
```

Currently, if you type or redirect to the `localhost/doctor/:id`, the `hasId` value gets an update. it the page exist, so the `hasId` will be `true`.

Finally, use `hasId` in your return method beside the `detail` tag:

```
return ( 
  <>
    {(detail || hasId) ? (
        <InnerDetail />
      ) : (  
        <Link
           to={{ 
             pathname: "/doctor/" + personData.id,
             state: { id: personData.id, data: personData },
           }}
           onClick={OpenInner}
         >
           <button style={styles.book}>Book Appointments</button>
         </Link>
      )}
  </>
)
```

You can also use another value to check the conditions:

```
const showInnerDetail = detail || hasId;

return ( 
  <>
    {showInnerDetail ? (
    // rest of the codes ....
```

Comment: here u have set up the useState ` const [hasId, setHasId] = useState(false) ` in `Details.js`

Comment: @MeenuKs yes, because you redirect your user into the details page. is this wrong?

Comment: as u can see in the code  `  /doctor/" + personData.id,  `  i am getting id from a api not as a pathname in  Details .js

Comment: I know that, but when your routes get change, the pathname will be changed and you need to confirm that with the procedure as I mentioned in the answer. try to read my answer step by step and think about the goals. @MeenuKs

Comment: i think u are expecting to get doctorId  as a number write but its not

Comment: no matter the doctorId type, it can be a number or string, but it's important to exist in your URL path to determine the page need InnerDetails or simple details @MeenuKs