# routing on click and pass a data also though routing : react js

Tags: reactjs

i am tryin to route to `localhost/detiled` on click on the `<li>`

when i type in url localhost/detiled my  `<InnerDetail />`  is loading i want the same when i click on the `<li>` tag
and also how can i access  `suggestion.id` in  `<InnerDetail />`

```
search.js  

<Link  to={{ pathname:"/detiled" }}
                >
                  <li
                    style={styles.listyle}
                    // onMouseOver={{ background: "yellow" }}
                    key={index}
                    className={classname}
                    onClick={finddoctor(suggestion.id)}
                  >
                    {suggestion.firstname}
                  </li>
                </Link>
```

in my path.js i have this

path.js

```
<Route path="/detiled">
 <InnerDetail />
 </Route>
```

```
import PersonPhoto from "../img/doctor.png";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Detail(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(false);
  //const data3 = location.state.data;
  //const doctor_id = data3.id;
  const inipath = window.location.pathname;
  const path = inipath.split("/cdoctor/");
  const [data3, setdata3] = useState([]);
  console.log(path[1]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    //remove this date after setting up the admin pannel

    axios
      .get(
        "doctor-filter/?id=" + path[1],
        config

        // config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        // setdata3(res.data);
      });
  });

 
  return (
    <>
      {/* {detail ? (
        <InnerDetail />
      ) : (
        <> */}
      <h4 style={{ textAlign: "left", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
        Top Specialities <i className="fa fa-angle-right"></i> /doctor/Detail
      </h4>
      <hr
        style={{
          margin: "30px 10px",
          background: "#fff",
          height: "1px",
          border: "none",
        }}
      />
      <div style={styles.wrapper}>
        {/* begin header */}
        <div style={styles.pheader}>
          <div>
            <div style={styles.pname}>
              <strong style={styles.namealigner}>Dr {data3.firstname}</strong>
              <br />
              <strong style={styles.namealigner}> {data3.lastname}</strong>
            
            </div>
            <hr style={styles.hr} />
            <div style={{ textAlign: "left", fontSize: "12px" }}>
              <span>
                {" "}
                {data3.speciality} | {data3.experience} years of Experience
              </span>
            </div>
            <hr style={styles.hr} />
          </div>

          <div>
            <img style={{ height: "100px" }} src={PersonPhoto} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end header */}

        {/* begin detail  */}
        <div style={styles.iflex}>
          <div style={styles.innerflex}>
            <i className="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
            <strong> Education</strong>
            <br />
            <small> {data3.qualification}</small>
          </div>

          <div style={styles.innerflex}>
            <i className="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <strong> Location</strong>
            <br />
            <small>{data3.location}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={styles.iflex}>
          <div style={styles.innerflex}>
            <i className="fa fa-user"></i>
            <strong> Registeration Number</strong>
            <br />
            <small>{data3.councilRegNo}</small>
          </div>

          <div style={styles.innerflex}>
            <i className="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <strong> Language</strong>
            <br />
            <small>English Malayalam</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end detail */}

      
      </div>
    </>
    // )}

    // </>
  );
}
```

this is the dashbord here serch is common in all pages

```
 <Search />

  <Specialities />
```

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const initialState = {
  idaddProducts: "",
};
const Searchclients = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(true);

  const [poName, pnName] = React.useState(initialState);
  const [showSerch, setShowSerch] = React.useState([]);
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedSuggestion, setSelectedSuggestion] = React.useState(0);
  const [displaySuggestions, setDisplaySuggestions] = React.useState(false);

  function finddoctor(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setDetail(true);
  }

  const suggestions = [];
  showSerch.forEach(function (data) {
    suggestions.push(data);
  });
  

  const onChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(value);
    setShowResults(false);

    //console.log(strung.substring(1, strung.length - 1));
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(suggestions));
    //   var suggestions = suggestions.substring(1, suggestions.length - 1);
    // newObj = suggestions;
    //console.log(suggestions);
    //setFilteredSuggestions({ ...poName, idAddProducts: idAddProducts });

    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      (suggestion) =>
        suggestion.firstname
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
        suggestion.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );

    // const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter((suggestion) =>
    //   suggestion.toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    // );

    setFilteredSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
    setDisplaySuggestions(true);
  };

  const onSelectSuggestion = (index) => {
    setSelectedSuggestion(index);
    setInputValue(filteredSuggestions[index]);
    setFilteredSuggestions([]);
    setDisplaySuggestions(false);
  };

  const SuggestionsList = (props) => {
    // console.log(props);

    const {
      suggestions,
      inputValue,

      onSelectSuggestion,
      displaySuggestions,
      selectedSuggestion,
    } = props;

    if (inputValue && displaySuggestions) {
      if (suggestions.length > 0) {
        return (
          <ul className="suggestions-list" style={styles.ulstyle}>
            {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              // console.log(suggestions);
              const isSelected = selectedSuggestion === index;
              const classname = `suggestion ${isSelected ? "selected" : ""}`;
              return (
                <Link to={`/detiled/${suggestion.id}`}>      //this isthe link
                  <li
                    style={styles.listyle}
                    // onMouseOver={{ background: "yellow" }}
                    key={index}
                    className={classname}
                   
                  >
                    {suggestion.firstname}
                  </li>
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        return <div>No suggestions available...</div>;
      }
    }
    return <></>;
  };

  

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("all-doctors-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        // pnName(data.data);

        //  var stringdata = data;
        setShowSerch(data);

        //console.log(stringdata);
      });
    //  setShowSerch(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="note-container" style={styles.card}>
        <div style={styles.inner}>
          <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Search Doctors</p>
          <form className="search-form" style={{}}>
            {showResults ? (
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                style={{ marginRight: "-23px" }}
                icon={faSearch}
              />
            ) : null}
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              value={inputValue}
              style={styles.input}
              type="Search"
            />

            <SuggestionsList
              onClick={() => this.nextPath("/detiled")}
              inputValue={inputValue}
              selectedSuggestion={selectedSuggestion}
              onSelectSuggestion={onSelectSuggestion}
              displaySuggestions={displaySuggestions}
              suggestions={filteredSuggestions}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};



export default Searchclients;
```

Comment: What is `suggestion.id` and how are you passing it to the "/detiled" route?

Comment: it a id  i want it like to pass it as url parms like if localhost/detailed/16    then suggetsion id is 16

Comment: I see, then MjZac's answer below should essentially be what you need. Can you clarify what you *actually* implemented of their solution and what you mean by "when i click on the li it does not route i think soming thing is not making the code route"? Please also update your question to include the component you are trying to link to, `InnerDetail`.

Comment: i have updated he code sir  @DrewReese

Comment: when i manualy type localhost/detailed my componet is loading but when i click on the <Link to={`/detailed}> it does not rouute  @DrewReese

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505097/link-path-not-working-as-expected-reactjs     as u can see the serch is common in al apges

Comment: Well, if you are linking to "/detiled" where there are no route params, then I wouldn't expect any to exist. If the `Detail` component is the `InnerDetail` component rendered on path "/detiled" then it also doesn't appear to attempt to access any route params. I'm not sure what relevance that other SO question has here other than that OP also has similar misunderstanding of routing in React.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238013/discussion-between-vivek-kn-and-drew-reese).

Comment: onClick={() => history.push("/detiled")} i remocvd this still it doesnot route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a route for detail view of the suggestion.

```
  <Switch>
  <Route path="/detailed" exact>
  list suggestions component
  </Route>
 <Route path="/detailed/:id" exact}>
  DetailComponent
  </Route>
 </Switch>
```

Then the link will become:

```
<Link to={`/detailed/${suggestion.id}`}>


    <li
      style={styles.listyle}
      // onMouseOver={{ background: "yellow" }}
      key={index}
      className={classname}
    >
      {suggestion.firstname}
    </li>
  </Link>
```

And in `DetailComponent` you can get the id from route  params.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { id } = useParams();  // the id passed in url
```

Comment: i tryed this when i click on the li it does not  route i think soming thing  is not making the code route

Comment: when i manualy type  localhost/detailed  my componet is loading but when i click on the  <Link to={`/detailed}>  it does not rouute

Comment: It should be <Link to={`/detailed/${suggestion.id}`}>
 not just <Link to={`/detailed}>

Comment: Since you are iterating to generate `Link`, you should add `key` attribute as well